# I accidently pressed 'No' to 'Do you want to save your changes' in Visio 2007. Can I recover?

Tags: microsoft-visio, file-recovery

Pretty straight forward question. Is recovering this file possible?

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible to recover.

Comment: Clear and short.

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between AutoSave and AutoRecover.

**AutoSave** is when the program regularly "saves" your working file for you.

**AutoRecover** is when the program closes or doesn't respond correctly, resulting in your working file(s) being lost.

Source: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Automatically-save-and-recover-Office-files-5baa2030-9768-4c6c-8d2a-1e10a8d741b1

From the Microsoft Office website (above) AutoSave is not available in Visio but, I believe, AutoRecover is available.

However, because you have confirmed to "not save" the document, Visio has cleaned up its areas and deleted any temporary and AutoRecover files (it closed expectedly!).

AutoRecover files are only kept in the event the Office application being used closes unexpectedly and, when you next run the application, it loads the files for you to save to an appropriate location.

The answer, unfortunately, is you will probably have no chance of recovering your file because you confirmed for Visio to not save your changes so it, accordingly, obliged.

Comment: Downvoter, are you sure? I'd have thought this answer is right, but only recently I was proven wrong about similar functionality for Excel. However, I don't know if Visio works the same as Excel.

Comment: Just imagine the situation where every application did save a file even if you said no, just in case.

Comment: Indeed, @Paul. But, fun fact: old versions of Excel (like Excel 97, I think) would prompt you to save workbooks, but then *not* give the workbook it was asking about focus. It would show the filename, I think, but surely I've been fooled into saying no, looking at a different workbook when seeing the prompt. (And just in case you didn't know: new versions of Excel indeed *do* keep a copy for some time, when you said no, for their [Recover Unsaved Workbooks](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/05/26/recover-unsaved-excel-file/) option.)

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you have autorecover enabled in Visio. In that case it should be possible to find the version which was auto-saved before you clicked "No".

As per [this KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/829239) you should inspect `%userprofile%\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Visio\AutoRecover11.ini` which contains the names of the files saved by autorecover. You may need to select the "show system files" option to make autorecover files visible in Explorer.

Comment: I don't see that article mentioning that choosing "No" when prompted to save, will in fact still retain the recovery data. (That said, Excel has a [Recover Unsaved Workbooks](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/05/26/recover-unsaved-excel-file/) option in its user interface nowadays, which works after choosing "No". So it may very well work like that in Visio too.)

Comment: To be honest I don't use Visio, but experience with Microsoft Office tells me those folders in AppData are worth inspecting if you want to recover your data. Since the article doesn't say that choosing "No" will wipe all autosaves, I hope for the best for the OP.

Comment: AutoRecover doesn't save files in the case (AFAIK).

Answer (score -1):

If you clicked "No", you can try to recover the file as described below:

1. Go to c:\users[username]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft[name office app]
2. Search to the date/time and **copy** the folder/file to a temporary location (ex: desktop)
3. Open the file from the temporary location, with the right Office app to see if this is the right version of the document.
4. Save the file like you normally would do.

Comment: Visio 2016 doesn't create a folder in the location you specified. Can you clarify the location?